# MarkerwithLabel suddenly not working

Tags: google-maps

I have no idea,why I am having too many error in my js when loading my map. Last week when I access my site its working fine my marker display properly on the map with no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe google has made some update try this

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.17"></script>
```